# Default permalink changes

Tags: permalinks

I need to use in my permalinks same titles for different post types and as far as I know the slug must be unique so the permalinks cannot be:

custom-post-type-1/hello-world

custom-post-type-2/hello-world

custom-post-type-3/hello-world

it will be like this:

custom-post-type-1/hello-world

custom-post-type-2/hello-world-2

custom-post-type-3/hello-world-3

how can I add a default -1 to the first permalink so the links will be like this:

custom-post-type-1/hello-world-1

custom-post-type-2/hello-world-2

custom-post-type-3/hello-world-3

Answer (score 0):

U could try one of these
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-permalinks/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/
I use them when i want to change my permalink structure, hope this helps u!